# Interrogate QSqlQuery on another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qsqlquery

Can you interrogate an QSqlQuery (eg. query.value) on a thread other than the one the connection/execution was made?

Comment: Have you tried it? Try it and tell us about your experience.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I want to. The code being multi-threaded it might take some time until it crashes randomly and I am more curious if the QSqlQuery architecture supports it

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module), this is **not** supported:

> A connection can only be used from within the thread that created it.
>   Moving connections between threads or creating queries from a
>   different thread is not supported.
>
> In addition, the third party libraries used by the QSqlDrivers can
>   impose further restrictions on using the SQL Module in a multithreaded
>   program. Consult the manual of your database client for more
>   information

So at the very least, you must [add a new database connection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase) (with a unique name) for each thread that you want to run a query from.

Comment: I'm referring to the usage of QSqlQuery after the execution. Does it cache the entire result? Does it use the connection if i'm just going through the records and read all the values?

Comment: @PascalauRazvan. So are you asking whether its possible to pass an active `QSqlQuery` object between threads? What problem are you trying to solve by doing that? Are you hoping to somehow avoid sending all the results back to the main thread?

Comment: @ ekhumoro I don't want to do the parsing of the result on the same thread the db connection was created on (I've serialized the access to happen on one thread instead of having multiple connections). And yes I want to know if I can use that active QSqlQuery on the caller thread.

Comment: @PascalauRazvan. I think it might be possible, but I have not tried it myself. Unfortunately, despite a lot of searching, I have not been able to find any official Qt statement on whether it is explicitly supported. It just does not seem to be something that is done very often. I have seen a few hints that iterating over the results in a different thread should be okay - but nothing really concrete. So it looks like you will have to find a way to experiment with it yourself.